# select same data from different db in same select statement

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

hi i want to select multiple db from linq in same select statement

```
// gets specific information from Cabinet table
var chassi = (from a in db.Cabinets
              from b in db.Commodities
              from e in db.sArticleNumbers

              where
                  kjopKollonne.Contains(e.ArtNum) &&
                  a.ArticleNumberID == e.ID &&
                  a.ArticleNumberID == b.ArticleNumberID

              select new {
                  ArtNum = e.ArtNum,
                  Price = b.Price,
                  ModelName = a.ModelName,
                           }).ToList();

// gets specific information from cpu table
 var cpu = (from a in db.cpu
            from b in db.Commodities
            from e in db.sArticleNumbers

            where
                kjopKollonne.Contains(e.ArtNum) &&
                a.ArticleNumberID == e.ID &&
                a.ArticleNumberID == b.ArticleNumberID

            select new {
                ArtNum = e.ArtNum,
                Price = b.Price,
                ModelName = a.ModelName,
            }).ToList();

// Joins CPU and chassi information to one output
            var query1 = (from a in chassi
                          from b in cpu

            select new {
                ArtNum = a.ArtNum and b.ArtNum, <-- problem
                Price = a.Price,
                ModelName = a.ModelName,
            }).ToList();
```

If any one has a different approach to solving it, thanks for posting it.

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear.

Comment: i want to join 2 LINQ querys to one they contain the same information, some information is gotten form a list and that list is to get the information (Artnum, price and modelname) from different table's  then join the output and display it. 

i know it should be solved in db but im not allowed to mess with it

Comment: What error do you get? `and` is not a C# keyword... do you get a compiler error?

Comment: i know and is not usable its just a psudo for want i want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the `Union` (removes duplicates) or `Concat` (keeps duplicates) methods.